# Why was it storming when Mad-Eye Moody enters?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Goblet of Fire* when Mad-Eye Moody enters into Hogwarts, it was storming in the Great Hall. Does this have anything to do with it being the wrong Moody?

Comment: When a shady character enters the fray for the 1st time in an event, this dramatization is common.

Comment: "[It was a dark and stormy night](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_was_a_dark_and_stormy_night)...."

Comment: Also known as Pathetic Fallacy :)

Comment: The storm doesn't bring Mad Eye Moody. Mad Eye Moody **is** the storm.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While there may have been a literary decision involved to have the Mad-Eye Moody character introduced along with thunder and lightning (it would certainly contribute to his frightening appearance), in universe there's nothing to suggest he was the cause of the storm. There had been bad weather for the entire day while they were travelling to Hogwarts on the Hogwarts Express.

Just after they board the train:

> Harry, Ron and Hermione went back to their compartment. The thick rain splattering the windows made it very difficult to see out of them.

It got worse as the journey progressed:

> The rain became heavier and heavier as the train moved further north. The sky was so dark and the windows so steamy that the lanterns were lit by midday.

The first mention of the storm itself is just after they arrived in Hogsmeade:

> Ron's bad mood continued for the rest of the journey. He didn't talk much as they changed into their school robes, and was still glowering when the Hogwarts Express slowed down at last, and finally stopped in the pitch-darkness of Hogsmeade station.
>
> As the train doors opened, there was a rumble of thunder overhead.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter Eleven - *Aboard the Hogwarts Express*</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I have another theory:

Do you remember in the 7th book and in the first part of the movie when Harry, Ron, and Hermione are trying to sneak into Gringotts and they go through a waterfall? It dispels both the Imperius curse they had on the goblin and their polyjuice potion.

My theory is based on how Moody's entrance is portrayed in the movies. The moment Moody (Crouch Jr.) steps out to join the hall, it immediately begins to storm and rain. I think the castle has a defense mechanism for situations like that and began to rain the same Dispel Magic water as the one in the 7th book/movie. Moody, realizing what is happening, uses a Confundus charm on the ceiling to keep it from noticing his polyjuiced self.

After seeing all of the films at least a dozen times, this is the first time I noticed this and have it click the gears into place.

Comment: Interesting idea. Do you have canon based support for your theory?

Answer (score -2):

When the fake 'Alastor' entered, he saw his father Barty Crouch Sr going to the podium. Barty Jr's mood was stormy and the ceiling reflected his feelings for his father. Similarly, Ron's mood affected the ceiling by snowing when he broke up with his girl in *Half-Blood Prince*.

Comment: Could you add some quotes illustrating this?

Answer (score -3):

You forget the fact that the ceiling of the Great Hall does not necessarily reflect the weather outside. In the movie Moody even says *'Stupid ceiling'*, suggesting that it might have a mind of its own and have reacted badly to him.

Answer (score -3):

The snow scene for Ron in *HBP* in the Great Hall after his sleep talk saying Hermione, and Lavender runs out,, it starts snowing as Ron looks at Lavender, and Hermione says "Stop it Ron! You're making it snow!" Hence the ceiling reflecting the emotions in the Great Hall, same for Fake Moody.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site LadyRiddle =) You know, I don't think there's any reason to imagine the snow was coming from the ceiling, it was just Ron being careless with his wand. In any case, this is really a movie thing, but I actually don't see any reason to think that the movies depart from the books, where the ceiling just shows the sky outside